# How to implement SabreDav/CalDav in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, webdav, sabredav

I'm trying to implement CalDav in CakePHP 3.0 and I'm new to both of them. I've created a Customer portal and want that every single user has access to his appointments.

I followed the tutorial http://sabre.io/dav/caldav/, but when I try to run mypage/calendarserver.php/ (which i've located in webroot), it only appears my own created login page (it should display a login from sabredav).

The real problem is: when I try to create for example: **"mypage/calendarserver.php/principals"** Cake tells me that the **principals controller is missing**. I don't want to use any controller of Cake when I access this url. Does somebody know how to avoid calling the controller of Cake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your login page appears that mean you are `unauthorised` to view that page. Have you tried adding that to `allow` ?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but yes, I added it.

Comment: The login works now (had to remove the slash at the end (mypage/calendarserver.php), but when i call mypage/calendarserver.php/calendars Cake still tells me I need a Calendar Controller. Any ideas?